# Ruby: How can I make these objects the same?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, each

So I have the following hashes/arrays:

```
{"number"=>[{"tracking"=>"1Z81E74W0393736553", "notes"=>"Example note"}, {"tracking"=>"9102901001301227214058"}]}

{"number"=>{"tracking"=>"1Z81E74W0393736553", "notes"=>"Example note"}}
```

That first hash has an array for `number` while the second one doesn't.

It's wreaking havoc trying to loop through the data (specifically when there's only one tracking/notes combo).

Ultimately I'm wanting to be able to do an `each` loop on each tracking/notes combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
h1={"number"=>[{"tracking"=>"1Z81E74W0393736553", "notes"=>"Example note"}, {"tracking"=>"9102901001301227214058"}]}
h2={"number"=>{"tracking"=>"1Z81E74W0393736553", "notes"=>"Example note"}}
[h1["number"]].flatten
  => [{"notes"=>"Example note", "tracking"=>"1Z81E74W0393736553"}, {"tracking"=>"9102901001301227214058"}]
[h2["number"]].flatten
  => [{"notes"=>"Example note", "tracking"=>"1Z81E74W0393736553"}]
```

Now, each will be an array of hashes and you can use `each` to iterate through them.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
hash["number"] = [ hash["number"] ] unless hash["number"].kind_of?(Array)
```